# Virtual Midi Keyboard software that displays inputs from electronic keyboard

Tags: windows, midi-virtual-keyboard

Please post links to a  Virtual Midi Keyboard software, which can take inputs from whatever is played via a Midi keyboard or from a score or midi song.

The output should be displayed on the computer screen with coloured notes. The size of the notes in the virtual software so ideally resemble piano sized keys

Comment: Are there any software packages you've already tried?

Comment: All I can think of that will come close (to the first half of the requirements) are any sequencer program, like cakewalk, or cubase, rosegarden, etc, but it would really help to know what OS you want and if you care if it is free or commercial.

Comment: Will be using Windows and the software should be minimalistic